# Swift Xcode - FittedSheets Errors

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods

I have just updated Xcode to the newest released version Xcode 12 and had updates my cocoa pods. I am now getting errors with 'FittedSheets' cocoa pod. I am not sure if they have released a new documentation on how to fix these errors but wanted to see if anyone has encountered and solved these errors.

```
let sheetController = SheetViewController(controller: vc, sizes: [.fixed(290)])
    sheetController.blurBottomSafeArea = false
    sheetController.adjustForBottomSafeArea = false
    // Make corners more round
    sheetController.topCornersRadius = 15
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Update your pods through terminal, this usually fixes the problem when swift updates.

Comment: I did update my pods when this happened after I updated my pods